# AWS/EC2 Status Text Stripped from Response

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-ec2, http-headers

My application is deployed on a set of docker containers on an EC2 instance.  In my local dev environment, I use the same set of docker containers.  My application sends back statusText headers to display meaningful error messages.  In my local environment, all of these statusText headers come back with the response just fine, but when the exact same code is deployed to AWS, the statusText header is always empty, which the browser appears to interpret as 'OK'.  The statusCode that I set comes back correctly.

tl;dr: Does anyone know of any behaviors on AWS or EC2 that would strip the statusText from the response headers?  I can't find anything in the documentation.

This doesn't return the status text:

```
server {
    listen       443 http2 ssl;
    server_name  api.example.com;
    root         /var/www/api/public;

    error_log    /var/log/nginx/api.error.log;

    client_max_body_size 16M;

    include ssl.conf;

    location / {
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin  '$cors_host';
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE,  OPTIONS";
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "$http_access_control_request_headers";
            add_header Content-Length 0;
            add_header Content-Type 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
            return 204;
        }
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '$cors_host';
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_url=$uri&$args;
    }

    include fastcgi_exec.conf;
}
```

This does:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  api.example.dev;
    root         /var/www/api/public;

    error_log    /var/log/nginx/api.error.log;

    client_max_body_size 16M;

    location / {
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers $http_access_control_request_headers;
            add_header Content-Length 0;
            add_header Content-Type text/plain;
            return 200;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_url=$uri&$args;
    }

    include fastcgi_exec.conf;

}
```

Comment: There's nothing about EC2 to explain this.

Comment: All I know is that it isn’t the containers and it isn’t the code.  I did at tcpdump on the host EC2 and the header is there, but after it makes its way through amazons infrastructure and back to the client, it’s gone.

Comment: Doing tcpdump is a good sign that you are on top of the troubleshooting process. Is this at the edge of the instance or is there anything in an outer layer (nginx?) that could manipulate the response?  What other infrastructure is involved?  A load balancer?  Which type?  Can you show what tcpdump captures and what you receive on the client side?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have done everything I can think, it was behind a dumb reverse proxy, so I removed that, I don't have any  Load Balancing or Firewall since the application is not live yet and access is limited by IP address.  I am completely stumped on this one.  I'll post my nginx configs from the dev environment, and the prod environment if that might help, although literally the only difference between the two is HTTPS/HTTP2

Comment: *"although literally the only difference between the two is HTTPS/HTTP2"* That's actually kind of a major, massive, difficult-to-overstate difference.

Comment: You said "header" and I thought you meant "header."  You're talking about, e.g., the `Not Found` message in `404 Not Found`.  That is not a thing in http/2.  Only the code is transmitted.

Comment: Well that explains it. Why in the hell couldn’t I find that in hours of googling?  At least all my errors are handled in one place.  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP/2 didn't preserve the "reason phrase" (status message) from HTTP/1.x.

> HTTP/2 does not define a way to carry the version or reason phrase that is included in an HTTP/1.1 status line.
>
> https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#HttpSequence

Comment: Apologies for the confusion around my referring to it as status text.  Years of doing full stack work has corrupted my nomenclature as pretty much every JS library in the universe refers to it as response.statusText or something similar.

Comment: This answer is very helpful. Unfortunately it's also a bit of a nightmare for existing code that relies on custom reason phrases.